# MySQL display rows where value IS NULL or IN(2, 3)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get enquiries that their teams are in 15, 9, 25, 26, 23, 18, 12 and null. The problems is the query doesn't retrieves the NULL records.

I have tried to use OR `team IS NULL` the query gives me all other statuses.

```
SELECT e.*,
FROM enquiries e
WHERE e.timestamp BETWEEN '1293840000' AND '1469055599'
  AND e.status IN(1) AND e.team IN(15, 9, 25, 26, 23, 18, 12, NULL)
ORDER BY e.timestamp ASC
```

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place OR condition in brackets

```
SELECT e.*,
FROM enquiries e
WHERE e.timestamp BETWEEN '1293840000' AND '1469055599'
AND e.status IN(1) AND ( e.team IN (15, 9, 25, 26, 23, 18, 12) OR e.team IS NULL)
ORDER BY e.timestamp ASC
```